# How to toggle tooltip programmatically in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have one chart and table with data related to it. I would like to show the given `tooltip` on `td` mouseover and hide tooltip on `td` `mouseout`. I've managed to create the first part.

```
var index = 5
var chart = $('#my-chart').highcharts()
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].points[index])
```

But **how can I hide the tooltip on mouseout**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `tooltip.hide()`.

Note: `tooltip.hide()` and `tooltip.refresh(point{}|points[])` is not part of official API ;)